# Simulating shutter angle for accumulative motion blur

Tags: opengl, image-processing

I am rendering accumulative motion blur(MB) in OpenGL the following way:
For each rendering frame I render N frames (N = number of MB steps) which represent interpolation of the transforms between the previous and current frame.

Now,I need also to add the shutter angle parameter into this effect.From the description I found [here](https://code.google.com/p/srcdemo2/wiki/ShutterAngle) the bigger shutter angle means longer exposure,but I don't really get how to translate this concept into practical implementation.I am sure I need to skip/add those "sub-frames" I render for each MB frame but is there an equation for doing this?

I have looked at how it works in Adobe AfterEffects and it looks that with the full shutter angle(360 degree) the MB interpolates completely from the previous frame to the current while with 180 it stretch only almost a half the way .

Comment: LMWTFY: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shutter_angle